# Unable to render the path of a ball

Tags: processing

I am trying to create gravity simulation. I want to draw a line to trace a ball's path, but due to the clear canvas from `background(0);` I am not able to do that.

```
float x = 10;
float y = 50;
float speedX = 2;
float speedY = 6;
float gravity = 0.98;
float red = 255;
float green = 0;
float blue = 0;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  fill(red, green, blue);

  if (mousePressed == false) {
    speedY += gravity;
    x += speedX;
    y += speedY;
  }



  if (x >= width || x <= 0) {
    speedX = -speedX;
    ;
  }

  if (y >= height || y <= 0) {
    speedY = -speedY;
  }
  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  line(x, y, 200, 200);
  circle(x, y, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses an ArrayList to hold the x and y values of the ball so that a path can be created:

```
float x = 10;
float y = 50;
float speedX = 2;
float speedY = 6;
float gravity = 0.98;
float red = 255;
float green = 0;
float blue = 0;

ArrayList<PVector> path = new ArrayList<PVector>();

void setup() {
  size(640, 660);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  fill(red, green, blue);

  if (mousePressed == false) {
    speedY += gravity;
    x += speedX;
    y += speedY;
  }

  if (x >= width || x <= 0) {
    speedX = -speedX;
  }

  if (y >= height || y <= 0) {
    speedY = -speedY;
  }
  path.add(new PVector(x, y));
  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  line(x, y, 200, 200);
  circle(x, y, 50);
  // Draw the path
  for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
    PVector p = path.get(i);
    line(p.x, p.y, 200, 200);
  }
}
```

**Addendum:**

The following example will draw path from ball to baseline.  Please note the reference where you can read more about ArrayLists:

```
//https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/arraylists

float x = 10;
float y = 50;
float speedX = 2;
float speedY = 6;
float gravity = 0.98;
float red = 255;
float green = 0;
float blue = 0;

ArrayList<PVector> path = new ArrayList<PVector>();

void setup() {
  size(640, 660);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  fill(red, green, blue);

  if (mousePressed == false) {
    speedY += gravity;
    x += speedX;
    y += speedY;
  }

  if (x >= width || x <= 0) {
    speedX = -speedX;
  }

  if (y >= height || y <= 0) {
    speedY = -speedY;
  }
  
  path.add(new PVector(x, y));
  // if path gets too long, remove first point
  if (path.size() > 100) {
    path.remove(0);
  }
  
  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  line(x, y, 200, 200);
  circle(x, y, 50);
  
  // Draw path from ball to baseline
  for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
    PVector p = path.get(i);
    line(p.x, p.y, p.x, height);
  }
}
```

**Third Option:**

This code will trace out the trajectory of the ball:

```
float x = 10;
float y = 50;
float speedX = 2;
float speedY = 6;
float gravity = 0.98;
float red = 255;
float green = 0;
float blue = 0;

ArrayList<PVector> path = new ArrayList<PVector>();

void setup() {
  size(640, 660);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  fill(red, green, blue);

  if (mousePressed == false) {
    speedY += gravity;
    x += speedX;
    y += speedY;
  }

  if (x >= width || x <= 0) {
    speedX = -speedX;
  }

  if (y >= height || y <= 0) {
    speedY = -speedY;
  }
         
  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  line(x, y, 200, 200);
  circle(x, y, 50);
  
  path.add(new PVector(x, y));
 
  for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
    PVector p = path.get(i);
    fill(0,255,0);
    circle(p.x, p.y, 5);
  }
}
```

**Fourth Option:**
Uses a line trace of the path instead of a small circle:

```
float x = 10;
float y = 50;
float speedX = 2;
float speedY = 6;
float gravity = 0.98;
float red = 255;
float green = 0;
float blue = 0;

ArrayList<PVector> path = new ArrayList<PVector>();

void setup() {
  size(640, 660);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  fill(red, green, blue);

  if (mousePressed == false) {
    speedY += gravity;
    x += speedX;
    y += speedY;
  }

  if (x >= width || x <= 0) {
    speedX = -speedX;
  }

  if (y >= height || y <= 0) {
    speedY = -speedY;
  }

  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  line(x, y, 200, 200);
  circle(x, y, 50);

  path.add(new PVector(x, y));

  for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
    PVector p = path.get(i);
    if (i>0) {
      PVector p1 = path.get(i-1);
      stroke(255);
      line(p.x, p.y, p1.x, p1.y);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sir its drawing from a fixed point can you give me a hint or suggest me such  that the line is being drawn to ball from it height from ground 
[current](https://ibb.co/PgrkZ8r)
```line(width , height, p.x, p.y);```

Comment: See addendum to original answer.

Comment: what is ```addendum``` sorry?

Comment: Addendum is referring to the second part of the answer.

Comment: Added a couple of more options to the answer.